# How to click a button (not a form) with Goutte PHP

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, screen-scraping, goutte

I do have this button on Bestbuy that shows the specifications of the laptop when clicked.
I also checked questions asked in stack overflow but none of them got answered.

This is the button:

```
<button class="c-show-hide-trigger c-accordion-trigger p-200 py-lg-300 px-lg-none flex align-items-center " type="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="specifications-accordion-content" data-track="Specifications: Accordion Close"><span class="c-accordion-trigger-label">Specifications</span><svg aria-hidden="true" role="img" viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="c-accordion-trigger-icon w-200 w-lg-300 mr-lg-200 c-accordion-rotate-caret-up"><svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M16.05 21.65a.97.97 0 0 1-.6-.2l-12.33-9.3A.98.98 0 0 1 4.3 10.6l11.75 8.85 11.74-8.85a.98.98 0 0 1 1.18 1.56l-12.34 9.3a.97.97 0 0 1-.58.2"></path></svg></svg></button>
```

I tried this code but it didn't work because it is not in a form. But I don't know how to click a button which is not in a form.

```
$button = $crawler->selectButton('Specifications')->form();
$client->submit($button);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Goutte does not execute JavaScript. Clicking a button would have no effect if it were possible.

Comment: yeah I realized that, thanks tho :D